# imgpanel.setImage(im); does not work in loop under button is pressed function but works fine in one pass

Tags: java, image

This loop works fine in **Main** function but when copy this **loop** code in under button pressed action then it does not work. It shows image only at the last iteration otherwise it shows blank.

```
public void buttonPressed() {
    BufferedImage im = null;
    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int j=100;
    for(int i=0;i<j;i++) {

        im = camera.captureImage();

        tracker.setImage(im);
        if (previous.x == -1) {
            // previous = tracker.searchCorrelation();
            previous = tracker.trackMarker();
        } else {
            // previous =tracker.searchCorrelation(previous);
            previous = tracker.sayemSearch(previous);
        }
        if (previous.x != -1) {
            System.out.println("prevX" + previous.x + "prevY" + previous.y);
            im = trackedImage(im, previous);
        }
        System.out.println("prevX" + previous.x);
        // System.out.println("prevY"+previous.y);
        imgpanel.setImage(im);
        System.out.println("set");
        //break;//When i write break then it works

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are blocking the event thread, so no repainting is done. If you want to display every image you will have to manually call `repaint()` on the panel or the frame after every `setImage`.

Comment: I had called repaint() function in setImage but it did not work.Would u please explain detail.

Comment: It might also be needed to call `repaint` on the top-level container, i.e. the frame/view/canvas.

Comment: But why it works fine in Main function.(i have mentioned above)

Comment: Your main function does not run inside the event thread. The `buttonPressed` function is called hen you press a button, right? The 'one' calling this `buttonPressed` method is the event thread ... and the event thread is also responsible for repainting. As long as you don't exit `buttonPressed` no other events can be handled, so you will only see the last image.

Comment: How to use a new thread to call the function repaint in above code ?? please help me